# getting Connection reset by peer error using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm getting this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

All I'm trying to do is the following in python:

```
import urllib, utllib2

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
id = response.read()
```

Some previous related questions suggested using `time.sleep` to fiddle with the threads. I didn't have any success with that but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Often "connection reset by peer" means that the target machine has a firewall that is actively blocking access to that port number. Are you sure you have the right port number (e.g. if it's not the default of port 80)?

Comment: Have you tried the url value in a browser (or wget, or...) to see if you can access the page from your test system?